# Is there a way to get the OneNote for Windows 10 search results in the Windows 10 start menu?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote

Microsoft has [deprecated the OneNote desktop app](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/onenote-2016-is-missing-after-installing-office-2019-or-office-365-1844ba87-7248-4bd8-a735-66a52f98e6e5) in favor of OneNote for Windows 10.

I'd love to tap the `Win` key and search through my files and OneNote notes.

Is there a way to index the OneNote for Windows 10 notes so they show up in the start menu search?

Comment: Hopefully someone else can chime in who has already found a way to do it, but based upon feedback from Microsoft is sounds like we can only [Search for notes in OneNote for Windows 10](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/search-for-notes-in-onenote-for-windows-10-01f1da59-8b41-4dc7-b060-9a220ad2ec57)

Comment: Try this, Control Panel>Indexing Options>Modify, now tick the C: drive then OK, now the entire drive will be indexed, it may take some time to index it all, now you should get some good search results. If you know the location of the OneNote archive folder, then you can just add that instead of the entire the C: drive.